# Avrstudio 4.19 toolchain using gcc 4.7.x

Tags: gcc, avr, atmel, atmega, avr-studio4

I'm using makefile style compiling of my ATMEGA projects. As legacy of Arduino IDE, develepment toolchain is mostly aimed to gcc 4.3.2. *Avrstudio 4.19 + Jtagice MKII CN + gcc 4.3.2 + make* works somehow. But my problem is that gcc 4.3.2 is rather buggy. I see e.g. random bugs related to optimization of non-volatile variables, register cached values are not always written back to memory and also wrong warning are annoying. Hence using **gcc 4.7.0** solves problem but I cannot load any such a program into Avrstudio 4.19, **Avrstudio always crashes when loading hex**. Does anybody tried and suceeded with this toolchain ?

Note: I don't want go to higher Avrstudio version because size grows and probably brings new problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [A Erasmus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3442323/a-erasmus) answer may have worked for avr-gcc 4.7.x; but I found in avr-gcc 4.8.1 provided by recent versions of the Atmel AVR Toolchain that AvrStudio4 didn't load any debugging symbols.

I noticed that the `.debug-pubnames` section was missing from the ELF file generated by avr-gcc 4.8.1 and that using the `-gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf -gpubnames` debug options reinstated the missing section which then allowed AvrStudio4 to show debugging symbols.

Comment: Yes! This solution is working with latest avr-gcc 6.1.x.

Answer (score 1):

If one uses the latest `avr-gcc` toolchain available from Atmel, then AVR Studio 4 crashes when trying to load the `.elf` file. To fix this change the debug flags from `avr-gcc` to `-gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf`. Then one can load and debug programs under AVR Studio 4 as normal.

Comment: Hmm, but gdwarf flags do not help at all. The AvrStudio keep crashing when Start debugging is executed. Might be related to JTAG programmer (I'm using chineese clone JTAGICE mkII-CN)? I can't prove it because when disconnected dialog box appears, i.e. I cannot tell at which particular phase it crashes. I don't know also what data are passed to JTAGICE.